# stop submitting of previous data of form on page reload to DB in jsp

Tags: java, sql, jsp, refresh

I have done the following coding 
ContactUs.jsp

```
<form action="contact1.jsp" method="post" id="contact_form">
                <div class="name">
                    <label for="name"></label> <input type="text" placeholder="My name is" name="name" id="name_input" required>
                </div>
                <div class="email">
                    <label for="email"></label> <input type="email"
                        placeholder="My e-mail is" name="email" id="email_input" required>
                </div>
                <div class="telephone">
                    <label for="name"></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="My number is" id="telephone_input" name="telephone" title="lenght of number should be 10 digits for valid number" pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" required/> 

                </div>

                <div class="message">
                    <label for="message"></label>
                    <textarea name="message" placeholder="I'd like to chat about"
                        id="message_input" cols="30" rows="5" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" id="form_button" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

the the code for contact1.jsp is

```
String name=request.getParameter("name");
String email=request.getParameter("email");
String telephone=request.getParameter("telephone");
String message=request.getParameter("message");

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/cinushi_university", "CinthiyaSingh", "Cinthiya@098");
Statement st=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs;
int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into contact values('"+ name + "','"+ email + "','"+ telephone + "','"+ message + "');");
if (i > 0) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("Message", "Sent Successfully!");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("ContactUs.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
else{
    request.getSession().setAttribute("Message", "Incomplete Process!");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("ContactUs.jsp").forward(request, response);   
}

//close connection
%>
```

Once I add the data to the form and submit it, this works fine, however post that on the same page when I click refresh it resubmits the data, I want the data from previous submission to clear when I redirect the response even to same ContactUs.jsp  , if it is possible please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use java script [History.replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState()() function to fix this issue.

The History.replaceState() method modifies the current history entry, replacing it with the stateObj, title, and URL passed in the method parameters.

Add this script in jsp page-

```
<script>
    if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
        window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
    }
</script>
```

Or,
Only insert data in table 'user' if submit data in not there. you have to check with unique column.